# php ssh linux screen exec

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I am trying to post a line of comments with PHP in Linux.
The first step I did was creating a new screen;

```
exec('screen -dmS stresstest.session');
```

This works without any problem. 
After this, I want to output for example the IP-address;

```
exec('screen -S stresstest.session -X stuff "ip addre $(echo -ne \'\\r\')"');
```

Here is where the problem kicks in;
Somehow it's impossible to comment the second line of code after the first one.

If I would make the Linux screen with my root user, and use php afterward to do a few times "ip addre", it works like a charm. 
When I create the screen with php and try the second line of code, it doesn't work.

What would here be the problem? 
I think it has something to do with the permissions right?

There were no errors.
It seemed like the script is working fine, but php doesn't execute the second and third commands.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Can u provide any error message you get when trying to run the second `exec` ?

Comment: There was no error while loading the PHP script. The new screen was made, but the second step and third step wasn't executed. No error has been outputed, only a string(0) messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen window numbering starts at 0. Try with `-p 0` instead.

Also, the `-X` parameter sends a command to the `screen` process itself not into the buffer controlled by `screen`.

If you run these commands in two terminals:

1. Terminal 1: `screen -dmS test`
2. Terminal 2: `screen -x test` (this will attach to your new `test` screen)
3. Terminal 1: `screen -S test -X echo message`

You'll see "message" appear in the screen message buffer (usually on the last line of the console where output of `^A w` etc appear).

I can't see a way to invoke a command or insert content directly into a running screen buffer.

The closest I can think of is to determine which PTY is associated with your running screen session and echo something directly to that. Not sure how you'd work out which is the correct one programatically though :-)

Inside screen:

```
$ tty
/dev/ttys002
```

Outside screen:

```
$ echo message >/dev/ttys002
```

I think this is probably getting a little too far away from what you intended though! What were you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I found this solution also on google. 
I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on "it doesn't work" then? Might give us a hint as to the problem.

Comment: I tried the following; screen -S stresstest.session -X stuff "ip addre $(echo -ne \'\\r\'), didn't work, als tried screen -S stresstest.session -p 0 -X stuff "ip addre $(echo -ne \'\\r\').

Comment: What were you expecting it to do? What did it do? Were there any errors?

Comment: The idea is to make a screen, and after the screen is made to insert a new comment like for example ip addre. There was no error output at all. The script seems to succeed, but the second and third step wasn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

I am building a stresstest device for asterisk in PHP.
The meaning is to create a loop and call with every new screen a phonenumber. 
This way I want to test how far Asterisk can go.

I fixed the problem. 
I was wrong, it has nothing to do with permissions.

I just needed to select the first screen.

```
-p 0
```

This one did it for me.

```
RUN_PJSUA       =    'screen -S stresstest.session -p 0 -X stuff "ip addre $(echo -ne \'\\r\')"';
```

Thank you!